# Jenkins Pipeline : Creating Tag in Git repository after successful build and upload archive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException while creating tag after build and publish stage

Requirement is need to create tag after build and upload artifact to nexus stage. Tag should be created as format V-{version_number}-${build_number }

Ex. V-6.00.1-20

And need push this tag to repository.

Upload archive task is in build.gradle

Written my pipeline as follows :

```
stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh './gradlew build -DbuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER} --no-daemon --stacktrace'
                }
            }
        }       
        stage ('Upload to Nexus') {
            when {
                expression { return env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop' || env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('release/') || env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('hotfix/') }
            }
            environment {
                NEXUS_CREDS = credentials('Nexus_Pass')
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh './gradlew uploadArchives -DnexusServer=$NEXUS_URL -DnexusUsername=$NEXUS_USER -DnexusPassword=${NEXUS_CREDS_PSW} -DbuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER} --no-daemon --stacktrace'
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Add GIT Tags') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: my_credentials, passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
                        sh "git tag V-{VERSION_NUMBER}-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                        sh "git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@myurl V-{VERSION_NUMBER}-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Getting missingProperty exception error

```
Commit message: "git tag changes"
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Add GIT Tags)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
 > /usr/bin/git clean -fdx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://stash1-tools.......git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Project deploy user
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --no-tags --progress https://stash1-tools....git +refs/heads/feature/devopsbranch-12759:refs/remotes/origin/feature/devopsbranch-12759 # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f c3e7d454e6d3525eec8ca939e9dcb07d98486b58 # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk c0b92f3a1238a0a313170b50975f31d382985d8c # timeout=10
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: your_credentials for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:290)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onGetProperty(GroovyInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:348)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:47)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:121)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: where does "your_credentials" come from? seems like the configuration you provided is not complete.

Comment: that credential id has been set in global jenkins repo

Comment: It's not present in the pipeline at all?

Comment: It is present. Actually i managed to tackle this error.